# jQuery: Count unique occurrences of class

Tags: jquery

I have a number of elements on my page that belong to classes with unique identifiers, based on my backend programming.  Such that I may have the following:

```
<element class="element-1"></element>
<element class="element-1"></element>
<element class="element-2"></element>
<element class="element-2"></element>
<element class="element-3"></element>
<element class="element-3"></element>
```

Is there a way I can count the unique occurrences of these classnames with jQuery, so that whatever function would do that would return `3`?

Comment: Yes: `function countUnique(element) { return 3 }`

Comment: No seriously, how did you get 3 as an answer to counting that example? I would have guessed you expected 2 as there're 2 of each class present.

Comment: I want to count the presence of the unique class names, of which there are three ("element-1", "element-2", "element-3"), not how many elements belong to each class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var obj = {};
var num = 0;
$("element[class^=element]").each(function() {
  var cl = $(this).attr("class");
  if(!obj[cl]) {
    obj[cl] = {};
    num++;
  }
});
alert(num);
```

Comment: I've read the jQuery documentation, still can't understand why that works?

Comment: Can be done in 1 line `alert($("element[class^=element]").length);`

Answer (score 56):

the answer is much simpler: `$("element.element-1").length;`